# Fast matrix multiplication with one symmetric circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, fast-fourier-transform, circulant-matrices

I have a symmetric circulant matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, a sparse matrix $G \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2m\times 1}$. I need to find the most numerically efficient way to calculate $M=Ax$. Where:

\begin{equation*}
    A = \frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
        GC^{-1}(GC^{-1})^T & -GC^{-1}(GC^{-1})^T \\
        -GC^{-1}(GC^{-1})^T & GC^{-1}(GC^{-1})^T \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Since $C$ is circulant, I know that $C^{-1}p = F^{-1}[\frac{F(p)}{F(c)}]^T$ which can be calculated very efficiently using the fast Fourier transform (FFT). Note $c$ is the first column of $C$. Perhaps there is an equivalent formula I can use for matrix multiplication to help me find $M$?

If it helps, I know I can rewrite the expression for $A$ as:

\begin{equation*}
2A =\begin{bmatrix}I \\ -I \end{bmatrix} GC^{-2}G^T \begin{bmatrix} I & -I \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Is this related to your previous question?

Comment: Yes, but it's a very different question. I've tried to break my massive engineering puzzle into a bunch of manageable bite sized chunks. If you like, I can share with you the full engineering puzzle - but I warn you, it's massive.

Comment: If they are part of the same project, then you can link them all and reveal the project in the last question